# How can I see the partitions?

Tags: partitioning

How can I see each partition in Ubuntu 11.10, similar to how they're displayed in Microsoft Windows? Information should be displayed for memory allocation.

*(Translated from German with the help of Google Translate and some guessing at what the question was asking for. See the [first revision](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/97803/1) for the original question text.)*

Comment: Diese Seite ist englisch! Versuch "Laufwerksverwaltung"

Answer (score 3):

You have several options. The most-like-Windows options are:

- Disk Utility (aka `palimpsest`) will let you see all your partitions, set up RAID arrays, run benchmarks, etc. It has slightly more features than you'll be used to in Windows but the interface is also slightly different. This is installed by default.
- `gparted` technically has a subset of `palimpsest`'s features but it's older. It won't help you set up RAID arrays but it does display partitions on drives in a relatively simple to understand manner. It also doesn't break things down by controller (as `palimpsest` does) but I don't want you to deter you from it. It's a very worthwhile tool for examining and changing a disk's partition layout.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the File systems tab in System Monitor.

[image]