# Home on its own partition

Tags: upgrade, partitioning, home-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I see the partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97803/how-can-i-see-the-partitions)

I have installed 11.10 and looking to do in place upgrade to 12.04 LTS.
I think I partitioned it such that home is its own partition so an upgrade could leave it insulated.  I have some questions

a) How do I confirm that home is its own partition.  Something I look for in df command?  I get all discombobulated with the `/sda1` and `/sdb2` and so on.

b) Can I install another linux and share the same home partition with it?

c) Are my software applications installed in the home partition so I don't potentially compromise them when I upgrade?

Thanks!

Comment: In the future please split up questions like this, the system is designed for one question per post, thanks!

Comment: -1 One question per question please. Also, [a is a duplicate of this](http://askubuntu.com/q/97803/12864), [b is a duplicate of this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6344), and [c is a duplicate of this](http://askubuntu.com/q/9024/12864).